# move_base launch fails due to: cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I was following the navigation tutorial for ROS Hydro installed on my UDOO board robot.

I follow the tutorial on the Navigation ROS Wiki but, launching the move_base.launch file, I have a

cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled

error.

Those are my yaml files:

base_local_planner_params.yaml

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.45
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_rotational_vel: 1.0
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.4

  acc_lim_th: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: false
```

local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
```

costmap_common_params.yaml

```
obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.30
inflation_radius: 0.55
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic; laser_scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: false
```

amcl_diff.launch:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
    <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
    <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
    <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
    <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
    <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
    <!-- translation std dev, m -->
    <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.8"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
    <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
    <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

and finally the move_base.launch

```
<launch>

  <include file="$(find geduino_navigation)/launch/amcl_diff.launch" />

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find geduino_navigation)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find geduino_navigation)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find geduino_navigation)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find geduino_navigation)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find geduino_navigation)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

When I try to launch move_base.launch I get this error message:

```
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:27,886: Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:27,898: Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:27,900: roslaunch starting with args ['/opt/ros/hydro/bin/roslaunch', 'geduino_navigation', 'move_base.launch']
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:27,900: roslaunch env is {'ROS_DISTRO': 'hydro', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'HUSHLOGIN': 'FALSE', 'CPATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/include:/opt/ros/hydro/include', 'LOGNAME': 'udoo', 'USER': 'udoo', 'HOME': '/home/udoo', 'PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/bin:/opt/ros/hydro/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel:/opt/ros/hydro', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/lib:/opt/ros/hydro/lib', 'LANG': 'C', 'TERM': 'linux', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'LANGUAGE': 'C', 'SHLVL': '1', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/udoo/.ros/log/fc4df7ea-3337-11e4-b578-7cdd9047677b/roslaunch-geduino-3197.log', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros', 'PYTHONPATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/pkgconfig', 'LC_ALL': 'C', 'ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR': '/home/udoo/ros/build/test_results', '_': '/opt/ros/hydro/bin/roslaunch', 'CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR': '/home/udoo/ros/build/test_results', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LC_MESSAGES': 'POSIX', 'OLDPWD': '/home/udoo', 'PWD': '/home/udoo/ros', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://localhost:11311', 'MAIL': '/var/mail/udoo', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'}
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:27,901: starting in server mode
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:27,902: starting roslaunch parent run
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:27,903: loading roscore config file /opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros/roscore.xml
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,360: Added core node of type [rosout/rosout] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch.config][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,361: loading config file /home/udoo/ros/src/geduino_navigation/launch/move_base.launch
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,507: Added node of type [amcl/amcl] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,678: Added node of type [move_base/move_base] in namespace [/]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,679: ... selected machine [] for node of type [amcl/amcl]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,679: ... selected machine [] for node of type [move_base/move_base]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,682: start_process_monitor: creating ProcessMonitor
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,683: created process monitor <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, initial daemon)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,684: start_process_monitor: ProcessMonitor started
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,685: starting parent XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,686: starting roslaunch XML-RPC server
[roslaunch.server][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,686: waiting for roslaunch XML-RPC server to initialize
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,687: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,688: Started XML-RPC server [http://geduino:55112/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,688: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,702: started roslaunch server http://geduino:55112/
[roslaunch.parent][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,702: ... parent XML-RPC server started
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,766: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,768: auto-starting new master
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,770: create_master_process: rosmaster, /opt/ros/hydro/share/ros, 11311
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,770: process[master]: launching with args [['rosmaster', '--core', '-p', '11311']]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,771: ProcessMonitor.register[master]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,772: ProcessMonitor.register[master] complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,772: process[master]: starting os process
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,773: process[master]: start w/ args [['rosmaster', '--core', '-p', '11311', '__log:=/home/udoo/.ros/log/fc4df7ea-3337-11e4-b578-7cdd9047677b/master.log']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,774: process[master]: cwd will be [/home/udoo/.ros]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,795: process[master]: started with pid [3210]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,797: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:28,899: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,001: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,103: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,205: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,307: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,409: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,511: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,518: master.is_running[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,523: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,530: setting /run_id to fc4df7ea-3337-11e4-b578-7cdd9047677b
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,538: setting /roslaunch/uris/host_geduino__55112' to http://geduino:55112/
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,548: ... preparing to launch node of type [rosout/rosout]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,548: create_node_process: package[rosout] type[rosout] machine[Machine(name[] env_loader[None] address[localhost] ssh_port[22] user[None] assignable[True] timeout[10.0])] master_uri[http://localhost:11311]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,549: process[rosout-1]: env[{'ROS_DISTRO': 'hydro', 'LESSOPEN': '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s', 'HUSHLOGIN': 'FALSE', 'CPATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/include:/opt/ros/hydro/include', 'LOGNAME': 'udoo', 'USER': 'udoo', 'HOME': '/home/udoo', 'PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/bin:/opt/ros/hydro/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games', 'ROS_PACKAGE_PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/src:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks', 'CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel:/opt/ros/hydro', 'ROS_LOG_FILENAME': '/home/udoo/.ros/log/fc4df7ea-3337-11e4-b578-7cdd9047677b/roslaunch-geduino-3197.log', 'LANG': 'C', 'TERM': 'linux', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'LANGUAGE': 'C', 'SHLVL': '1', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/lib:/opt/ros/hydro/lib', 'ROS_MASTER_URI': 'http://localhost:11311', 'PYTHONPATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 'ROS_ROOT': '/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': '/home/udoo/ros/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/pkgconfig', 'LC_ALL': 'C', 'ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR': '/home/udoo/ros/build/test_results', '_': '/opt/ros/hydro/bin/roslaunch', 'CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR': '/home/udoo/ros/build/test_results', 'LESSCLOSE': '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s', 'LC_MESSAGES': 'POSIX', 'OLDPWD': '/home/udoo', 'PWD': '/home/udoo/ros', 'ROS_ETC_DIR': '/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros', 'MAIL': '/var/mail/udoo', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'}]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,683: process[rosout-1]: args[[u'/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosout/rosout', u'__name:=rosout']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,684: ... created process [rosout-1]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,684: ProcessMonitor.register[rosout-1]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,685: ProcessMonitor.register[rosout-1] complete
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,685: ... registered process [rosout-1]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,686: process[rosout-1]: starting os process
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,687: process[rosout-1]: start w/ args [[u'/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosout/rosout', u'__name:=rosout', u'__log:=/home/udoo/.ros/log/fc4df7ea-3337-11e4-b578-7cdd9047677b/rosout-1.log']]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,687: process[rosout-1]: cwd will be [/home/udoo/.ros]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,700: process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3223]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,703: ... successfully launched [rosout-1]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,706: load_parameters starting ...
[roslaunch][ERROR] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,714: load_parameters: unable to set parameters (last param was [/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/min_in_place_rotational_vel=0.4]): cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,859: ProcessMonitor.shutdown <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 731092080)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,888: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 731092080)>
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,889: ProcessMonitor._post_run <ProcessMonitor(ProcessMonitor-1, started daemon 731092080)>: remaining procs are [<roslaunch.nodeprocess.LocalProcess object at 0x809070>, <roslaunch.nodeprocess.LocalProcess object at 0x7f2e50>]
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,894: ProcessMonitor exit: killing rosout-1
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,895: [rosout-1] killing on exit
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,898: process[rosout-1]: killing os process with pid[3223] pgid[3223]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,899: [rosout-1] sending SIGINT to pgid [3223]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:29,899: [rosout-1] sent SIGINT to pgid [3223]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,201: process[rosout-1]: SIGINT killed with return value 0
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,201: ProcessMonitor exit: killing master
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,202: [master] killing on exit
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,205: process[master]: killing os process with pid[3210] pgid[3210]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,206: [master] sending SIGINT to pgid [3210]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,209: [master] sent SIGINT to pgid [3210]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,415: process[master]: SIGINT killed with return value 0
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,416: ProcessMonitor exit: cleaning up data structures and signals
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,416: ProcessMonitor exit: pmon has shutdown
[rospy.core][INFO] 2014-09-03 07:00:30,425: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

I checked my code several times for tabs, ,missing spaces on yaml file, namespace usage but I was not able to find a fix.
Can someone help me to fix it?

Thanks a lot
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191773/move_base-launch-fails-due-to:-cannot-marshal-none-unless-allow_none-is-enabled/) by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) on 2014-09-03**:
Wrong reason. The right reason to close this question is RESOLVED.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-03**:
You can also click the check box next to my answer to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see anything obvious wrong with your parameter files.

This sort of error usually happens when there's a missing parameter somewhere. The best way to narrow it down is to start commenting out the `<rosparam>` lines in your move_base launch file until you find the line that's causing problems, and then take another look at that file to figure out why it fails to load.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ahendrix,

following your suggestion I found the error: ';' used instead ':' in costmap_common_params.yaml

Thanks for your support.
Alessandro

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hansolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29473/hansolo/) on 2019-02-28**:
For me it was indentation mismatch in a yaml file.